# PowerShell compare CSV to AD Subnets and update / add if required

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've got a CSV file with headers subnet, site, description. I want to import this into PoSH and then compare what is in AD Sites and Services. Now, this might be "null" or it might already contain subnet values. In either case, I need the subnets in AD compared to the CSV and updated/added as required.

I thought about If/Else, but that doesn't seem to handle the scenario where no subnets exist.
So I moved to try/catch and also `Compare-Object`.

Anyway, an example of what I've tried:

```
$csvSubnets = Import-Csv -Path C:\subnets.csv
$adSubnets = Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter *

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($csvSubnets | Select-Object) -DifferenceObject @($adSubnets | Select-Object) -Property Name | Where-Object {
    $_.SideIndicator -eq '<='
} | ForEach-Object {
    $csvSubnetName = $_.subnet
    $csvSiteName = $_.site
    $csvDescription = $_.description
    $adSubnetName = $adSubnets.Where({$_.Name -eq $csvSubnetName})
    New-ADReplicationSubnet -Site $_.site -Name $_.subnet -Description $_.description
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
New-ADReplicationSubnet : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Site'. The argument is null
```

Would anyone have a suggestion as to how to fix this, or perhaps a more efficient way of achieving what I need? Doesn't need to be computationally efficient as there's probably never more than 10 sites (subnets)

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I'd point out is you aren't passing the original objects coming out of the comparison to the `ForEach-Object` loop.  Either reference the property `$_.InputObject` or preferably use the `-PassThru` parameter on the `Compare-Object` command:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($csvSubnets | Select-Object) -DifferenceObject @($adSubnets | Select-Object) -Property Name -PassThru | 
Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} |
ForEach-Object {
    $csvSubnetName  = $_.subnet
    $csvSiteName    = $_.site
    $csvDescription = $_.description
    $adSubnetName   = $adSubnets.Where({$_.Name -eq $csvSubnetName})
    New-ADReplicationSubnet -Site $_.site -Name $_.subnet -Description $_.description
}
```

An aside:

The `Compare-Object` command is rather hard to read, given intermingled pipelines. It may be better to establish those as variables separately.  However, you aren't specifying any properties in those `Select-Object` commands.  I presume you are trying to level-set the typing to `[PSCustomObject]`'s in which case you should really only need to do that with the rich objects returned from `Get-ADReplicationSubnet` `Import-Csv` will always return `[PSCustomObject]`.  So you could revise a little like:

```
$csvSubnets = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\subnets.csv'
$adSubnets = Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter * | Select-Object *

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csvSubnets -DifferenceObject $adSubnets -Property Name -PassThru | 
Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} |
ForEach-Object {
    $csvSubnetName  = $_.subnet
    $csvSiteName    = $_.site
    $csvDescription = $_.description
    $adSubnetName   = $adSubnets.Where({$_.Name -eq $csvSubnetName})
    New-ADReplicationSubnet -Site $_.site -Name $_.subnet -Description $_.description
}
```

I can't test your code but after solving the first problem you may have another with this line:

```
$adSubnetName = $adSubnets.Where({$_.Name -eq $csvSubnetName})
```

You aren't referencing the `.Name` property after you've isolated the AD Subnet you're interested in.  I might be missing something, but if you do have that problem a quick fix might be something like:

```
$adSubnetName = ($adSubnets.Where({$_.Name -eq $csvSubnetName})).Name
```

Also, I like the `.Where()` method, but I'm a little iffy on it's return types, and on the readability of unnecessarily mixing and matching.  You could replace with a regular `Where{}` clause:

```
$adSubnetName   = ( $adSubnets | Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq $csvSubnetName } ).Name
```

**Update:**

It is true that if the difference object is null the `Compare-Object` command will fail.  However, that approach stemmed from your original code. There are actually many ways to extract the difference between 2 lists.  Here's a more concise example:

```
$csvSubnets = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\subnets.csv'
$adSubnets = (Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter *).Name

$csvSubnets |
Where-Object{ $_.Name -notin $adSubnets } |
ForEach-Object{
    $SubnetParams = @{
        Name                  = $_.subnet
        Site                  = $_.site
        Description           = $_.description
    }
    New-ADReplicationSubnet @SubnetParams
}
```

In this case we use the `-notin` operator against a list of subnet names.  `$adSubnets` isn't being used for anything else.  We don't need it to be objects custom or otherwise. Now for each record in the CSV file just see if the name isn't on the list, and if not proceed to create the subnet.

Speed is not a likely concern in this case however you can actually make the above example a little more efficient using If logic in the loop and eliminating the `Where{}`.

```
$csvSubnets = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\subnets.csv'
$adSubnets = (Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter *).Name

$csvSubnets |
ForEach-Object{
    If($_.Name -notin $adSubnets ) {
        $SubnetParams = @{
            Name                  = $_.subnet
            Site                  = $_.site
            Description           = $_.description
        }
        New-ADReplicationSubnet @SubnetParams
    }
}
```

In either example the key point is that `-notin` will work fine even if the right hand side of the comparison is null.  It's simply return false and therefore the subnet will get created.

Comment: Thank you. Although this doesn't seem to handle the "null" response if there are no subnets in AD Sites and Services and it errors if it finds a subnet already in AD Sites and Services that matches.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I used your Where{} code block example (the last code segment), but this doesn't update the subnets, or add them.

Comment: There was a typo from an earlier revision. I corrected it.  I can't test the code, but the concepts should be solid.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you to the other responses here which lead me down a slightly different path to a solution.

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$csvSubnets = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path C:\subnets.csv

foreach ($subnet in $csvSubnets) {

    $ADSubnetName = $subnet.subnet

    if ($S = Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter {Name -eq $ADSubnetName}) {
        Write-Verbose "Subnet $($ADSubnetName) already present"
        Continue # to the next subnet
    }

    $SubnetParams = @{
        Name        = $subnet.subnet
        Site        = $subnet.site
        Description = $subnet.description

    }
    Write-Verbose "Created subnet $($ADSubnetName)"
    New-ADReplicationSubnet @SubnetParams

}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional information. Above has some practical issues.  Generally you don't want to repeatedly call a cmdlet to check for presence of an object.  Also there's no reason to assign `$S` in the if logic. If this is part of a larger function Verbose is fine, otherwise `Write-Verbose` won't do anything unless the $VerbosePreference` is set to continue.

Comment: It also looks like you've mixed up some of the variable names, `$ADSubnetName` is assigned to the value coming from the CSV data. unless it's a syntax preference you don't really need that variable, but as long as it's there the "AD" prefix serves to confuse the reader as if the data came from AD when in fact it's from the CSV file.